# Django Rest Framework: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-gis

I'm using Django Rest Framework to create REST endpoints for a frontend.
I have a model where there is the possibility of uploading 3 images (**foto_1**, **foto_2**, **foto_3**).

```
class Ocorrencia(TimeStampedModel):

(...)

foto_1 = models.ImageField("Foto 1", upload_to="ocorrencias/", blank=True)
foto_2 = models.ImageField("Foto 2", upload_to="ocorrencias/", blank=True)
foto_3 = models.ImageField("Foto 3", upload_to="ocorrencias/", blank=True)
```

My serializer is the following:

```
class OcorrenciaSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):

(...)

foto_1 = serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, allow_null=True, required=False, use_url=True)
foto_2 = serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, allow_null=True, required=False, use_url=True)
foto_3 = serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, allow_null=True, required=False, use_url=True)

class Meta:
    model = models.Ocorrencia
    geo_field = 'geometria'
    fields = ('foto_1', 'foto_2', 'foto_3')
```

If for example foto_3 has no file url associated in the database (it's saved as empty string when it's empty) then I get the following error when **retrieving** the associated endpoint:

**Exception Value: The 'foto_3' attribute has no file associated with it.**

Using **allow_empty_file=True**, **allow_null=True**, **required=False** when defining the serializer for the image fields seems to not do anything.

**UPDATE 1**

I found that this is related to using GeoFeatureModelSerializer, this is part of [Django Rest Framework GIS](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis). I'll have to seek a solution on that route. If I happen to use the default serializer class of DRF I have no issues. I was almost going insane with this issue. If I find a solution using GeoFeatureModelSerializer I'll post it here.

**UPDATE 2**

Updated Django-Rest-Framework-Gis to latest version and fixed it. Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: Are you consuming the API response in a template? Are you rendering  it in a template?

Comment: No, just accessing the json endpoint in the browser and get that error.

Comment: Have you tried setting the max_length=None?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't have any effect also.

Comment: Try `allow_blank=True` if that works in your case

Comment: It doesn't allow allow_blank in the serializer.ImageField.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and i specified the source attribute as source='image.name' but that was with rest framework 2

Comment: Adding source='foto_3' for example gives a redundancy warning as the source is the same.

Comment: @greven does it still raise the exception?

Comment: It gives a different exception: 

__"It is redundant to specify `source='foto_1'` on field 'ImageField' in serializer 'OcorrenciaSerializer', because it is the same as the field name. Remove the `source` keyword argument."__


Still can't be able to access the json endpoint.

Comment: @greven change it to source='foto_1.name', there seems to be an issue with DRF image fields similar issue here https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2494. In your models the upload_to can be changed to upload_to='ocorrencias' without the trailing slash which might potentially cause other issues.

Comment: If I add source='foto_1.name' I get a different exception:

**Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'url'**

Comment: @greven have you tried removing all the attributes except required=False? This must be an issue with DRF or I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Yes I tried using **required=False** alone, same result.
This might be something obvious too, but I'm not seeing the solution even if obvious.

I would expect the image field to be null for an empty ImageField but it just gives an exception instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79912/discussion-between-greven-and-pieter-hamman).